# Definition of RMS deviations from mean w.r.t. $|u(x,0)|^2$ and $|A(k)|^2$ in Jackson

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, fourier-transform, probability, statistics

In chapter 7 of Jackson’s *Classical Electrodynamics* (page 323) he speaks of ‘‘rms deviations from mean, $\Delta x$ and $\Delta k$, defined with respect to $|u(x,0)|^2$ and $|A(k)|^2$’’. I do not understand how do I calculate $\Delta x$ and $\Delta k$?

Answer (score 0):

1. What Jackson calls the root-mean-square (rms) is really the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Definition_of_population_values)
   $$\Delta x\equiv\sigma_x=\sqrt{\langle (x-\langle x\rangle)^2\rangle}=\sqrt{\langle x^2\rangle-\langle x\rangle^2},$$
   and similarly for $\Delta k$. The [rms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) is really $\sqrt{\langle x^2\rangle}$ but physicists sometimes use both terms as the same, as can be seen [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-61-physical-chemistry-fall-2007/lecture-notes/lecture9.pdf), [here](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Etsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Heisenberg_uncertainty_principle-2.html#RMS_deviation_in_quantum_mechanics), and mentioned [here at the end](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Root-Mean-Square.html).
2. To find $\Delta x$ and $\Delta k$ in terms of $|u(x,0)|^2$ and $|A(k)|^2$ respectively, notice the expressions for $u(x,0)$ and $A(k)$
   $$u(x,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty A(k)e^{ikx}dk$$
   $$A(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,0)e^{-ikx}dx.$$
   $u(x,0)$ and $A(k)$ are Fourier transforms of each other, and basically $|A(k)|^2$ tells you how much is the plain wave with wavenumber $k$ contributing to the wavepacket $u(x,0)$ and similarly for $|u(x,0)|^2$ and $A(k)$. So when calculating the means $\langle (x-\langle x\rangle)^2\rangle$ and $\langle (k-\langle k\rangle)^2\rangle$, $|u(x,0)|^2$ and $|A(k)|^2$ act as probability density functions:
   $$\Delta x^2=\langle (x-x_0)^2\rangle=\int (x-x_0)^2p(x)dx$$
   $$\Delta k^2=\langle (k-k_0)^2\rangle=\int (k-k_0)^2p(k)dk$$
   with $p(x)=|u(x,0)|^2$ and $p(k)=|A(k)|^2$.